# Navigation between differents UI in vaadin project

Tags: user-interface, vaadin, vaadin7

please I have a vaadin project with 2 UI ,I want to go from the first UI to the second by clicking a button. Have you any idea how can I do it .Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a Vaadin application only contains just a single `UI`, and then Vaadin `Navigator` is used to switch between different views.

But sometimes there is a valid use case for multiple `UI`s inside the same application.

If you have multiple `UI`s, to open the UI, which is running in the context root of your web app, you could just say:

```
getUI().getPage().setLocation("/");
```

and if you have an another `UI` running at path `second`, you can open it by calling:

```
getUI().getPage().setLocation("/second");
```

Comment: It would require to defined two vaadin servelts, wouldn't it?